# How to return a view with populated drop-downs when ModelState is invalid?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httpclient

I have a couple of controllers that call APIs to get data to populate form drop-downs.
Is there a way to return to the same view to display model state errors without calling the API again?

Controller method 1 [GET]:

Calls API to get a list of organizations and return a view along with the list of organizations to populate the dropdown.

Controller method 2 [POST]

When the ModelState is invalid, I would like to return the view to display the Model State errors but without writing the same code from controller 1 to get the list of organizations.

If Model State is Invalid:
I could redirect to controller method 1 [GET] but the model state errors get lost. If I call the API to request the list of organizations inside the POST method I will be writing the same code as in controller method 1.

Question: Is there a good way to do this?

Comment: Store errors in `TempData` in method 2, then redirect to method 1 and read the errors out of `TempData` to populate them in your view.

Comment: Both modes need to use the same instance of the view.  So you need to pass the same instance to both model classes.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways you can do this:

### 1. Move your API-calling code into its own method, and return `View` instead of redirect:

If the only code that would have to be duplicated is the code that populates data from the APIs, that's a good case for extracting that code to its own method.

I would add the data to the `ViewBag`/`ViewData` - which basically allows you to send information besides the page's model from the Controller to the View. The `ViewBag` only lasts for *one request* - once you perform another request (such as a redirect), the `ViewBag` is empty. So within every controller action that needs data from the APIs, you would call the method that gets that data.

For example:

```
// could also be named something like "FillDropdowns"
public void InitializeViewData()
{
    // call your APIs here
    var orgData = YourAPI.GetOrganizationList();

    // add the data returned by the API to the ViewBag/ViewData
    ViewData["Organizations"] = orgData;
}
```

And then in the View, you'll use `ViewData["Organizations"]` or `ViewBag.Organizations` as the source of the data for the dropdown.

Then in your two controller methods, call your new `InitializeViewData()` method and return a `View` from each. They'll look something like this:

```
// Controller method 1 [GET]
public ActionResult GetView()
{
    // call API to fill organizations
    InitializeViewData();

    return View("ViewName");
}

// Controller method 2 [POST]
public ActionResult Submit(ModelObj model)
{
    // ...

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // instead of redirecting to "Controller method 1" ...
        // return RedirectToAction("GetView");

        // ... call your API and return the View
        InitializeViewData();
        return View("ViewName", model);
    }
}
```

By returning a View rather than redirecting, your `ModelState` will be accessible on the page after a validation error, and you can do with it whatever you need to do.

### 2. Use `TempData`:

If your "controller method 1" is more complex than just calling the API(s) and returning a View, and the code in it doesn't belong anywhere else (like the model), you can use `TempData` instead.

`TempData` allows you to pass data from one request to another. This means you can add something to the `TempData` before you redirect, then access it in the controller action immediately after the redirect.

So you would add your model errors or a custom error message to the `TempData` in your "controller method 2". Then in "controller method 1", you check for the existence of that `TempData` key - if it exists, you then add it to the `ViewBag`/`ViewData` so it can be accessed in the View.

```
// Controller method 2 [POST]
public ActionResult Submit(ModelObj model)
{
    // ...

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // add to TempData
        TempData.Add("Errors", ModelState.SerializeErrors()); // you could add the whole object
        TempData.Add("ValMsg", "Some custom error message");  // or just a message
        
        // redirect
        return RedirectToAction("GetView");
    }
}

// Controller method 1 [GET]
public ActionResult GetView()
{
    // call API to fill organizations
    // ...
    
    // check for TempData (whatever you named the key)
    if (TempData.ContainsKey("ValMsg"))
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = TempData["ValMsg"];
    }

    return View("ViewName");
}
```

Then in your View you would do something like this:

```
@if (ViewBag.ErrorMessage != null)
{
    <div class="error-message">@ViewBag.ErrorMessage</div>
}
```

---

See [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476967/What-is-ViewData-ViewBag-and-TempData-MVC-Option-2) for more information about the lifecycle of the `ViewBag` and `TempData`.